# Templating using RequireJS (text.js plugin) and Underscore

Tags: javascript, templates, backbone.js, underscore.js-templating

Need some opinions on the best way to manage templating in Underscore. I'm building a Backbone app and using Underscore to manage the templates. I started off by doing something like this in a 'template.js' file.

```
templates = {
    template1: '<h1>Some HTML</h1>',
    template2: '<h1>Some more HTML and a <%= variable %></h1>
    ...
}
```

This gets messy. Fast. So, I looked into RequireJS's [text plugin](https://github.com/requirejs/text) and that makes it much cleaner. Now, I have a bunch of HTML files, and I essentially store it into my 'templates' object. Something like this:

```
define(['text!/templates/template1.html',
    'text!/templates/template2.html',
    ...], 
    function(template1, template2, ...) {
        return {
            template1: template1,
            template2: template2,
            ....
        }
});
```

So now the issue is HTTP requests. For templates alone, I have 5 requests - 1 for the template.js file, and then 4 separate HTML template files. And that list is going to keep growing. One thing I was thinking was to put all of the HTML in one file, but that doesn't seem to go with the AMD methodology. As the app progresses, I can be a lot smarter about this and only load HTML templates when necessary - if they're all separate.

Is there any way around all of the HTML requests? I assume this is not good practice in a production environment.

Anyone have any other ideas for how to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what the [RequireJS Optimizer](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) is for. It combines all of your modules into a single file as part of your pre-deploy build process. According to the [README for the text plugin](https://github.com/requirejs/text):

> The text files are loaded via asynchronous XMLHttpRequest (XHR) calls, so you can only fetch files from the same domain as the web page (see XHR restrictions below).
>
> However, the RequireJS optimizer will inline any text! references with the actual text file contents into the modules, so after a build, the modules that have text! dependencies can be used from other domains.